# image uploading through editor

Tags: php, image, upload, editor

I am trying to upload image for my application through an editor. I am using php. I think default tinymce is not so much flexible at least for a user. So is there any editor by which user can add image which will be from their computer? If so please let me know.

Comment: You have innova editor. That editor supports what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Great one, but paid:
**Readctor** - http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Easy-looking, easy-writeble functions (and for custom uploading ajax script too)